# HibernateTemplate.find returns list of DefaultElement instead of Hibernate Entity

Tags: hibernate, spring, hibernate-mapping, classcastexception

Why does the following part of code produces "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement cannot be cast to cc.co.sqeezer.model.Registration"

```
List list = this.getHibernateTemplate().find(query, parameters); 
if (list.size() > 0) { 
        registration = (Registration) list.get(0); // here is ClassCastException
}
```

Mapping is:

```
<class name="Registration" table="registration" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="version">
<meta attribute="implement-equals">true</meta>
<meta attribute="implement-tostring">true</meta>

<id name="registrationId" type="integer" column="registration_id" unsaved-value="none">
  <meta attribute="scope-set">public</meta>
  <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>

  <!-- generator class="native"></generator -->
  <generator class="sequence">
    <param name="sequence">registration_registration_id_seq</param>
  </generator>
</id>

<property name="emailAddress" column="email" type="string" not-null="true">
  <meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>
  <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
</property>
<property name="password" column="password" type="string" length="50">
  <meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>
  <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
</property>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource" /></property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>cc/co/sqeezer/model/Mappings.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Where is the DefaultElement coming from?

Comment: can you publish the **query** you are using?

Comment: query is `String query = "from Registration as registration where registration.emailAddress = ?";`. Parameter is not null. The solution was to add `hibernate.default_entity_mode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found solution myself.
The following HibernateProperty was added

```
<prop key="hibernate.default_entity_mode">pojo</prop>
```

Seems dom4j is the default entity mode in my case.
Look to the properties [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-properties).